# Stopwatch download speed calculate with other speed formats

Tags: c#, stopwatch, webclient

I downloading one file with WebClient.DownloadFile(address, fileName) class.

And I calculating download speed with Stopwatch.

My speed calculation code;

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
labelSpeed.Text = string.Format("{0} kB/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024 / stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));
```

I want to show download speed "b/s, kb/s, mb/s, gb/s, etc..." formats, but my code is providing only "kb/s" format. How to show other formats?

Comment: The 1024 is doing the conversion to kb, so bytes would be the same formula without the division (or a division of 1), mb would be divided by 1024* 1024, etc.

Comment: Doing `e.BytesReceived / 1024d` is giving you `kB/s`, not `kb/s`. There's a difference between bytes and bits.

Comment: @MartinCostello - It's a conversion to kB, not kb.

Comment: @MartinCostello - There's also no `mb` - it's either `Mb` or `MB` (depending if you wants megabits or megabytes).

Comment: @Enigmativity, thanks for your answer. Which value does it make sense for a download application? kB or kb? Mb or MB? (Bytes or Bits?)

Comment: @KellyBailey - These days it is usually `MB/s` for downloading an app as app sizes are usually quoted in `MB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Enum to to avoid cloning the code for the display. Here an example:

```
enum ByteMassFactor { B = 1, KB = 1024, MB = 1024 * 1024, GB = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 }

void Main()
{
    var byteCount = 2048;

    foreach (var mass in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ByteMassFactor)).Cast<ByteMassFactor>().Reverse())
        if (byteCount / (int)mass >= 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{byteCount / (int)mass} {mass}");
            break;
        }
}
```

Output:

```
2 KB
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've solved my problem simply by using this way for now;

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

string downloadSpeed;

downloadSpeed = string.Format("{0} B/s", (e.BytesReceived / stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));
if ((e.BytesReceived / stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds) > 1024)
{ downloadSpeed = string.Format("{0} KB/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024 / stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00")); }
if ((e.BytesReceived / 1024 / stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds) > 1024)
{ downloadSpeed = string.Format("{0} MB/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024 / 1024 / stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00")); }
if ((e.BytesReceived / 1024 / 1024 / stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds) > 1024)
{ downloadSpeed = string.Format("{0} GB/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00")); }

labelSpeed.Text = downloadSpeed;
```

Comment: This worked while I couldn't find the right calculation. But I question the conditional overhead in such a async operation.